# C#: error when saving an image to the Documents folder

Tags: c#, vb.net, bitmap, filepath, inputbox

I have an image displaying on my C# form. When the user clicks "Save Image" button it pops up a Visual Basic input box. I am trying to add functionality to my form which allows the user to save the image when they enter the name of the image through the visual basic input box.

First, I added this code,

```
private void save_image(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String picname;
        picname = Interaction.InputBox("Please enter a name for your Image");            
        pictureBit.Save("C:\\"+picname+".Png");                      
        MessageBox.Show(picname +" saved in Documents folder");
    }
```

However, when I run the program and click the save button it gives this exception: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"

Then I added few changes to the code to make it look like this,

```
private void save_image(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();            
        String picname;           
        picname = Interaction.InputBox("Please enter a name for your Image");
        savefile.FileName = picname + ".png";
        String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        using (Stream s = File.Open(savefile.FileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            pictureBit.Save(s, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        //pictureBit.Save("C:\\pic.Png");           
        MessageBox.Show(picname);                                
    }
```

When I run this code, it doesn't give the exception anymore but it saves the image in my c#->bin->debug folder. I know this might not be the ideal way of doing it but how do I set it's path so it saves the image in the documents folder.

Comment: you are not setting the path

Comment: How do I set the path? That's what I don't understand

Comment: try something like `savefile.FileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.png", path, picname);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
savefile.FileName = path + "\\" + picname + ".png";
```

Other working example with show dialog:

```
SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

savefile.InitialDirectory = path;
savefile.FileName = "picname";
savefile.Filter = "PNG images|*.png";
savefile.Title = "Save as...";
savefile.OverwritePrompt = true;

if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Stream s = File.Open(savefile.FileName, FileMode.Create);
    pictureBit.Save(s,ImageFormat.Png);
    s.Close();
}
```

Other save example:

```
if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    pictureBit.Save(savefile.FileName,ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked after adding your code and a minor change. It should be two back slashes not one.

Comment: When I decided to save the image, firstly, I tried to use somewhat quite similar to your second example. However, it gave an exception saying "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll" which I didn't understand how to fix so that's why I tried the VB inputbox method. Do you have any idea how to fix this exception?

Comment: SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
            savefile.FileName = "img.png";
            savefile.Filter = "PNG files (*.png)|*.png|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (Stream s = File.Open(savefile.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    pictureBit.Save(s, ImageFormat.Png);
                    
                }
            }

Comment: I'm sorry it looks really messy I don't know how to edit it on the comment section here

Comment: Show me definition of pictureBit

Comment: private Bitmap pictureBit;

Comment: it is actually a mandelbrot fractal. what I am trying to do is draw a fractal on to the screen and then allowing the user to save it

Answer (score 0):

you are not setting the path, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filename.aspx) for more info.